# spring обновление данных чере sql и через jpa

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

обновляю данные через sql  всё просто находим запись и делаем инкремент

```
public  void setStatisticByIdUrl(Long urId) {
    this.jdbcTemplate.update("update  statistic set count = count + 1" +
            " where url_id = ?", urId);
}
```

ну да ладно тут понятно, запустил тестирование в многопоточке, создал 10 тысяч задач в 10 потоков , на выходел получил count 10000
т.е. всё правильно,
теперь попробуем сделать тоже самое средствами спринга jps  и т.д...

```
@Transactional
public void setStatisticByIdUrl(Long urId) {
    Statistic statistic = this.statisticRepository.findFirstByUrlId(urId).orElse(new Statistic());
    statistic.setCount(statistic.getCount() + 1);
}
```

на выходе получаю не 10тысяч а 2000 иногда 3.5 тысяч потокобезопасность отсутствует на прочь, добавление к аннотации  serializable  и т.д. ничего не меняет - почему ?

Comment: там опечатка я про спринг jpa  писал ...

Comment: Почему не вызываете `statisticRepository.save()`?

Comment: потому что это транзакция и по окончанию метода неявно вызывается flush и происходит синхронизация кеша с базой данных с последующим очищением кеша, если б у меня  анотация @Transactional не работала то данные в бд вообще бы не менялись но они меняются до 2000 иногда до 3000 иногда до 2500